# SAPUI5: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined on elementBinding

Tags: javascript, binding, sapui5

I'm trying to do some operations after a successful data binding of the view. The best idea would be in my opinion to do it in the callback of the **attachModelContextChange** method. After defining which method would be the callback and attaching the event listener to the view, when I try to bind data to my view, I get the error: **Cannot read property 'call' of undefined**. I'm pasting my controllers code fragments below and the stack trace.

```
    onInit: function() {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.routeMatched, this);
    },


    routeMatched: function(oEvent) {
        var sEntityPath,
            oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();

        this.routeName = oParameters.name;

        this.getView().detachModelContextChange(
            this.modelCallback('edit'),
            this.getView()
        );

        if (oParameters.name === "EditItem") {
            if (!isNaN(oParameters.arguments.id)) {
                this.getView().attachModelContextChange(null,
                    this.modelCallback('edit'),
                    this.getView()
                );
                sEntityPath = "/ItemData(" + oParameters.arguments.id + ")";
                this.getView().bindElement(sEntityPath);
            } else {
                var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                oRouter.navTo("CreateItem", {
                    from: "EditItem"
                }, false);
            }
        }
    },

    modelCallback: function(type) {
        console.log(type);
    }
```

The **console.log** from the **modelCallback** method is launching properly. Removing the line with

```
this.getView().bindElement(sEntityPath);
```

prevents the error from triggering (but this way I'm of course not getting any data in my view).

Any ideas what am I missing?

Below I'm pasting the stack trace:

```
datajs.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at f.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:449)
at f.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:991)
at f.fireModelContextChange (sap-ui-core.js:573)
at f.h.setElementBindingContext (sap-ui-core.js:524)
at constructor.i (sap-ui-core.js:500)
at constructor.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:449)
at constructor.B._fireChange (sap-ui-core.js:1302)
at eval (library-preload.js:2375)
at u (library-preload.js:2460)
at d.r._processSuccess (library-preload.js:2492)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect parameters in attachModelContextChange call. The only required parameter is a callback function, modelCallback in your case. You pass null as oData optional parameter which can be omitted. The correct call should look like this:

```js
       this.getView().attachModelContextChange(
            this.modelCallback, // the function, not the result of its call!
            this // Instance of controller (not View!), which is now *this*
        );
```

Also, the call of detachModelContextChange should be with the same parameters to make it work:

```js
this.getView().detachModelContextChange(
  this.modelCallback, // the function, not the result of its call!
  this // Instance of controller (not View!), which is now *this*
);
```

when you place this.modelCallback('edit') at the parameter list then first the function is executed and then its result is passed as a parameter to attachModelContextChange (or detachModelContextChange)

Comment: Ok, this solves the problem. But is there a way that would make this work with that parameter being passed (my intention was to use the same callback method but with a different parameter - now I have to use two separate callback methods instead of parameterizing the one example from above)?

Comment: Yes, you can: 
this.getView().attachModelContextChange(
            your_data,
            this.modelCallback, // the function, not the result of its call!
            this // Instance of controller (not View!), which is now *this*
        );
even better see here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/attachModelContextChange

Answer (score -1):

```
        onRowSelect:function(oAnubhav){
            //alert("Yes, Row Selection Worked Roger !");
            //step1 get the path of the selection item.
            debugger;
            var sPath= oAnubhav.getParameter("rowContext").getPath();
            //step2 transfer the  element data to the simpleformcontrol,using bind element.
            
            //2.1 get the object of simpleform-parent of all input.
           // var oSimple=this.getView().byId("idSimple");

            //2.2the entire simpleform new recives data form table elementselected.
           //oSimple.bindElement(sPath);
           this.getView().bindElement(sPath);

        },
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.